# RegExp PHP get text between multiple span tags

Tags: php, regex, tags, match

I don't speak English very well. So, if i'll make some mistake please sorry.

On the site i have a div box with some information about game:

```
<span class="noteline">Developer:</span> 
<span class="subline">Gameloft</span> 
<span class="noteline">Genre:</span> 
<span class="subline">Racing/Arcade</span> 
<span class="noteline">Release year:</span> 
<span class="subline">2010</span>
```

I need to get the information between `<span class="noteline">` and it's closing tag `</span>`

```
preg_match("/\<span\sclass=\"subline\"\>(.*)<\/span\>/imsU", $source, $matches);
```

the solution above works fine but it only gets the "subline" with text "gameloft";

but i need also sublines that have text Racing/Arcade and 2010;

Maybe something like this (that doesn't work);

```
for developer = preg_match("/*(\<span\sclass=\"subline\"\>){1}*(.*)*(<\/span\>){1}*/imsU", $source, $matches);
for genre = preg_match("/*(\<span\sclass=\"subline\"\>){2}*(.*)*(<\/span\>){2}*/imsU", $source, $matches);
```

something like this..

Anyway. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to regexps would be to use phpQuery or [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/), which simplifies it to:

```
foreach ( qp($source)->find("span.subline") as $span ) {
    print $span->text();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are not appropriate to parse HTML. They are difficult to get right and they always break in edge cases.

I don't know if there's an easier way but this should work with the markup you describe:

```
<?php

$fragment = '<span class="noteline">Developer:</span>
<span class="subline">Gameloft</span>
<span class="noteline">Genre:</span>
<span class="subline">Racing/Arcade</span>
<span class="noteline">Release year:</span>
<span class="subline">2010</span>';

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($fragment);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
libxml_use_internal_errors(FALSE);

foreach($xml->xpath("//span[@class='subline']") as $item){
    echo (string)$item . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This assumes `class="subline"` so it'll fail with multiple classes. (New to Xpath so improvements welcome.)

Comment: Just what I needed, didn't knew about that DOMDocument class, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all("/<span class=\"subline\".*span>/", $html, $matches);

preg_match_all("/<span class=\"noteline\".*span>/", $html, $matches);
```

I tried the above code this way:

```
<?php 

$html = '<span class="noteline">Developer:</span> 
<span class="subline">Gameloft</span> 
<span class="noteline">Genre:</span> 
<span class="subline">Racing/Arcade</span> 
<span class="noteline">Release year:</span> 
<span class="subline">2010</span>';

preg_match_all("/<span class=\"subline\".*span>/", $html, $matches1);

preg_match_all("/<span class=\"noteline\".*span>/", $html, $matches2);

print_r($matches1);
echo "<br>";
print_r($matches2);

?>
```

The output I got was this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Gameloft [1] => Racing/Arcade [2] => 2010 ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Developer: [1] => Genre: [2] => Release year: ) )
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That seems to be a great solution.